# Where should this URL point to if I am using Java instead of PHP?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the following jqGrid script:

```
   jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({        
       url: "editing.php?q=1",
       datatype: "xml",
       // ...
```

Where should the `url` point to if I am using Java instead PHP for creating the crud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should just point to an URL where you've some Java code running and listening on the particular URL. In a Java webapplication you normally use a Servlet class for this. Just let the URL match the `<url-pattern>` of the Servlet class as you've definied in the `web.xml`. In the Servlet class you just implement [`doGet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method accordingly to handle the HTTP GET request and response.

Comment: I am not using servlet for my program. Because i am using DWR here.So do i need to call the remote method here.? How to make this jquery to call my edit funtion in the place of that URL.??

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DWR, specify a function as your datatype (instead of "xml") that calls the DWR Javascript method. The DWR function's callback should then call the editGrid's addXMLData like so:

```
$("#editGrid")[0].addXMLData(xmlData)
```

note the [0] notation, which is neccesary.
Details here: [JQGrid Wiki: methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)